# max of space separated values in a column with string type in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a column of type string in my dataframe with value as '1  1  1  3'. I need to update the column with max of the value in pyspark.

I have tried with UDF converting string to list and then back to string. Can there be a simpler way

Sample Data: Link below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOEM4.png)

TIA.

Comment: Can you try and post a sample of your data, and your expected output?

Comment: added image link above. Thanks!

Comment: please, do not add images. You can read this if you need more information : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and then [`array_max`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_max):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

a = [["1 1 1 3"]]
b = ["foo"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

df.withColumn("bar", F.array_max(F.split("foo", " "))).show()

+-------+---+
|    foo|bar|
+-------+---+
|1 1 1 3|  3|
+-------+---+
```